# TikZ automata: size of circle around nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am trying to replace vaucanson-g with TikZ, but I cannot make the automata as small. There seems to be a minimum size of the circle around nodes, that I can't reduce even with `inner sep=0`. Example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [->,auto,node distance=0.6cm,line width=0.4mm]
 \node[state,initial,inner sep=1pt] (q) {$q$};
 \node[state,accepting] (p) [right=of q] {$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A lot of whitespace is left around the letters.

Comment: Please include a full compilable example including `\documentclass` and all the packages (especially with `tikz`) and not just code snippets.

Comment: @Peter percusse and I took that liberty.

Answer (score 16):

Adding `inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0pt` does the job for me.

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [->,auto,node distance=0.6cm,line width=0.4mm]
 \node[state,initial,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0pt] (q) {$q$};
 \node[state,accepting,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0pt] (p) [right=of q] {$p$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to set this explicitly, because `state` is (basically) defined as `circle,draw,minimum size=2.5em`. To change this globally, add `\tikzset{every state/.style={minimum size=0pt}}`.