# how to decrease the size of the circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to draw a binary tree like this:

[image]

I have come up with the code below, but the size of the circle is too large. I tried to decrease the size, however, failed, can someone tell me how?

```
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
   \usepackage{wrapfig}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
   \resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
block/.style = {circle, draw,
        text width=2em,align=center,radius=.05cm},
    line/.style = {draw,thick, -latex'},
    node distance=0.9cm and 0.4cm
    ]

    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (a) {a};
    \node [block, below left of=a,xshift=-1.0cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (b) {b};
    \node [block, below right of=a,xshift=1.0cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (c) {c};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (a) -- (b);
\path [line] (a) -- (c);

\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: How did you try to decrease the size? You should change the value of `text width` in your `block` style. Depending on how small you want your circles to be, you might also need to set a smaller value for `inner sep` (the default is `2pt`).

Comment: I try to set the radius, but it seems to not take any effect

Comment: `radius` is only used for `\draw (0,0) circle [radius=...]` commands, it doesn't have an effect on node sizes. Try altering `text width` and `inner sep`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [TikZ automata: size of circle around nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29151/tikz-automata-size-of-circle-around-nodes/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion in Jake's comments,  I replaced ***radius=0.05cm*** by something like ***text width = 0.05cm***. Below is your modified code.

```
\documentclass{minimal}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
block/.style = {circle, draw,
align=center,text width = 0.1cm, inner sep = 0.1cm},
line/.style = {draw,thick, -latex'},
node distance=0.9cm and 0.4cm
]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (a) {a};
    \node [block, below left of=a,xshift=-1.0cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (b) {b};
    \node [block, below right of=a,xshift=1.0cm, yshift=-0.3cm] (c) {c};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (a) -- (b);
\path [line] (a) -- (c);

\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{document}
```

You should get the following output.

[image]

Comment: If you set it to a value that small, you should just remove the `text width` parameter completely, then the circle size will always match the contents.

Comment: so do you know how to add words in the arrow that from "a->b"

Comment: @Jake, thanks. What would be a good rule of thumb for setting up the values?

Comment: @sweetyBaby, perhaps a `\path [line] (a) -- node [sloped, above] {From $a$ to $b$} (b) ;`? Then try to increase your node distance.