# Tikz: Padding in finite automata nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, automata

If I write in the code of a state diagram of finite automaton:

`\tikzset{every state/.append style={shape=ellipse, inner sep=0pt}}`

Then my state nodes look like this:

[image: nodes]

I would like to get rid of nearly all of padding between state label and circle, so my nodes should look e.g. like this:[image: nodes2]

Any suggestions how to do it? Negative inner sep does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Solution can be found here -> [TikZ automata: size of circle around nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29151/tikz-automata-size-of-circle-around-nodes/29160#29160)

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29160/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza -> Thanks, it works!